# Ajax over SSL works on Mozilla Firefox, but not on IE

Tags: ajax, apache, ssl

As the subject states my hunch it has something to do with IE and *certificates*, but I need an expert opinion.

***Background:***
My ajax url looks something like this: [https://<serverIpAndPort>/<contextRoot>/getUserGroups]

This url works fine on Mozilla Firefox. However on IE 8,9 I get a **500 Internal server error** exception. I should mention at this time, there is no problem on IE 8,9 when it is running in a non-ssl fashion. I am pretty convinced its not a javascript browser compatibility issue.

I will really appreciate if I can get some expert opinion here and a way to get around this issue. Our company is very pro IE and this web application has to work with SSL turned on.

**Environment:** Apache with Reverse Proxy and SSL on
Web Logic Application Servers using WL_Plugin and SSL on.

Comment: Please first check if there is something blocking port 443 in your IE. You can start by opening Internet Explorer and typing https://www.microsoft.com:443 in the Address bar.

Comment: Amber: I was able to access microsoft.com:443 using IE.

What should I try next?

Comment: If there is some way that you could create a test application and replicate the issue there ? That would help a lot in solving the issue.